# How do I create a mysql database for my nodejs project?

Tags: mysql, node.js

This should be really basic and simple to do but I can seriously not find *any* understandable information on how to *create* a simple database for my nodejs typescript project.

I have installed the following packages with npm:

- mysql2
- sequelize
- sequelize-cli
- sequelize-typescript

I have attempted the following commands at the terminal

```
C:\repos\NodeNew>mysql2 -u root -p
'mysql2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\repos\NodeNew>mysql -u root -p
'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\repos\NodeNew>node mysql2 -u root -p
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\repos\NodeNew\mysql2'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3

C:\repos\NodeNew>
```

So how do I CREATE my database so I can connect to it with sequelize etc?

Answer (score 1):

The tools you have installed are only for connecting a Node.js app to MySQL and do not include command-line tools to manage the MySQL server.

I will assume you have installed MySQL and it's running – you should then be able to find its `mysql.exe` command line client in the `bin/` directory in the server's installation directory. If you haven't fiddled with authentication, just running it might work.

When you get to a MySQL prompt, you can follow any old instructions for creating a database; `CREATE DATABASE foo;` is the gist of it (authentication and permissions being a different story).

Since you're on Windows, you might want to look into [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) – it's been a while since I've used it, but it's a decent graphical MySQL management tool.

You *can* also use `mysql2` to create the database – illustrated below – but I recommend getting a management tool.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'mysql',
});
connection.query('CREATE DATABASE foo');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I thought I had installed it before because something related to mysql keeps updating itself on my computer. But apparently I hadn't. I have something called mysql workbench or something. Anyways now I have installed Mysql server. Do you know how to tell it to put the database file in the same folder as my nodejs project?

I assume I have to install mysql server on the hosting space for my website in the future?

Comment: MySQL takes care of its database files and their locations by itself, and you can't really move them around. If you need an SQL database contained in a single file, look into SQLite instead. And yes, your web host would need to support MySQL; if it's a shared server, it's usually not something you can install yourself. If it's a VPS, then sure.

Comment: hmmm interesting. So if I develop my database locally (i e put in all the info etc), how do I move it over to the server if I can't grab the files and copy/upload them to the appropriate location? Do I have to enter all data again, manually, onto the server?

Comment: No – you can use the `mysqldump` utility to grab a textual copy which you can then apply onto your production server.

Answer (score 0):

You should have MySQL installed on your computer, to install mysql on Windows see the following page: [MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-installing-windows.html) 
Once you have MySQL up and running on your computer. Open the Command Terminal and execute the following:

```
npm install mysql
```

Now you have downloaded and installed a mysql database driver. Node.js can use this module to manipulate the MySQL database:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

To create a conecction create a file connection.js:

```
 var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

to test it save the file and run:

```
 node connection.js
```

Which will give you this result:

```
 Connected!
```

Comment: IDK I had mysql Workbench installed since before but apparently it wasn't working? Now I also have MySQL server installed. But when I try to import my mysql2 module with `import mysql2 from "mysql2";` I get the error `Could not find a declaration file for module 'mysql2'. 'c:/repos/NodeNew/node_modules/mysql2/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/mysql2` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'mysql2';`ts(7016)`

Comment: @coding_pianist you dont have to make an import declare it as a variable like this: 
const mysql = require('mysql2'); [example](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/)

Comment: Ok sweet that worked, thank you! Now I just have this error `Parameter 'err' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)` on the err in the function you provided `con.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});`

Comment: @coding_pianist try to changue the function like this:                                                                     connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected!');
});

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using beforeConnect hook of sequelize as below:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];

const { host, port, username, password } = config;

# create sequelize instance without providing db name in config
sequelize = new Sequelize('', username, password, config);

sequelize.beforeConnect(async (config) => {
     const connection = await mysql.createConnection({ host: host, port: port, user: username, password: password });
     await connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${process.env.DB_NAME}\`;`);
     config.database = process.env.DB_NAME;
});
```

Config.json file contains configurations for different dbs like

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": "init@123",
    "host": "mysqldb",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql",
  }
}
```

Database name is provided after db connection and creation(if required) in sequelize beforeConnect hook